# If key values match, merge and reduce. Restructuring JSON data response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am trying to restructure my fetched JSON data. A sample of my JSON response is here:

```
{
  "sys": {
    "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 3,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID1",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "John's Title",
        "building": "John's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1234,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID2",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Jane's title",
        "building": "Jane's Building",
        "roomNumber": 4321,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID3",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Bob's title",
        "building": "Bob's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1111
      }
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "Asset": [
      {
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID1",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "johndoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID1/1234567890/JohnDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JohnDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID2",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "janedoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID2/0987654321/JaneDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JaneDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to take the **fields** key and properties from the **includes > Asset** and put them into the correct **item > fields > picture** that has the matching **ASSETID**. Then the **includes** would just be removed from the whole thing because it is no longer needed.

This is what the final result that I want:

```
{
  "sys": {
    "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 3,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID1",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "John's Title",
        "building": "John's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1234,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID1"
          },
          "fields": {
            "title": "johndoe",
            "file": {
              "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID1/1234567890/JohnDoe.jpg",
              "details": {
                "size": 16681,
                "image": {
                  "width": 244,
                  "height": 352
                }
              },
              "fileName": "JohnDoe.jpg",
              "contentType": "image/jpeg"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID2",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Jane's title",
        "building": "Jane's Building",
        "roomNumber": 4321,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID2"
          },
          "fields": {
            "title": "janedoe",
            "file": {
              "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID2/0987654321/JaneDoe.jpg",
              "details": {
                "size": 16681,
                "image": {
                  "width": 244,
                  "height": 352
                }
              },
              "fileName": "JaneDoe.jpg",
              "contentType": "image/jpeg"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID3",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Bob's title",
        "building": "Bob's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1111
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I currently have is a function that iterates over each item in **items** and tries to see if the **Assets** array includes the **ASSETID** from the item.

```
const items = data.items.slice(0);
const assets = data.includes.Asset.slice(0);

items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.fields.picture !== undefined) {
    const {
      id
    } = item.fields.picture.sys;
    const mappedAssets = assets.map(asset => asset.sys.id);

    if (mappedAssets.includes(id)) {
      console.log('This id matched:', id)
    }
  }
})
```

```js
const data = {
  "sys": {
    "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 3,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [{
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID1",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "John's Title",
        "building": "John's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1234,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID2",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Jane's title",
        "building": "Jane's Building",
        "roomNumber": 4321,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID3",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Bob's title",
        "building": "Bob's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1111
      }
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "Asset": [{
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID1",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "johndoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID1/1234567890/JohnDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JohnDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID2",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "janedoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID2/0987654321/JaneDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JaneDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const items = data.items.slice(0);
const assets = data.includes.Asset.slice(0);

items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.fields.picture !== undefined) {
    const {
      id
    } = item.fields.picture.sys;
    const mappedAssets = assets.map(asset => asset.sys.id);

    if (mappedAssets.includes(id)) {
      console.log('This id matched:', id)
    }
  }
})
```

I'm not sure how to spread the properties in the way that I want to. Am I going in the right direction or is my thinking off?

The solution ended up being:

```
    data.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.fields.picture !== undefined) {
        const { id } = item.fields.picture.sys;
        const foundAssets = data.includes.Asset.find(asset => asset.sys.id === id);
        item.fields.picture = { ...item.fields.picture, fields: {...foundAssets.fields} };
      }
    });
    delete data.includes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess could simply use `forEach`, do the matching, spread what is required and delete what is not required. Something like this

```js
const input = {
  "sys": {
    "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 3,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [{
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID1",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "John's Title",
        "building": "John's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1234,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID2",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Jane's title",
        "building": "Jane's Building",
        "roomNumber": 4321,
        "picture": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Asset",
            "id": "ASSETID2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "SPACEID"
          }
        },
        "id": "ENTRYID3",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:51.318Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "master",
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Environment"
          }
        },
        "revision": 1,
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "ContentType",
            "id": "contentTypeID"
          }
        },
        "locale": "en-US"
      },
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "title": "Bob's title",
        "building": "Bob's Building",
        "roomNumber": 1111
      }
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "Asset": [{
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID1",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "johndoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID1/1234567890/JohnDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JohnDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": {
          "space": {
            "sys": {
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Space",
              "id": "SPACEID"
            }
          },
          "id": "ASSETID2",
          "type": "Asset",
          "createdAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.369Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-05-22T15:03:41.370Z",
          "environment": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "master",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Environment"
            }
          },
          "revision": 1,
          "locale": "en-US"
        },
        "fields": {
          "title": "janedoe",
          "file": {
            "url": "//some.image.link/SPACEID/ASSETID2/0987654321/JaneDoe.jpg",
            "details": {
              "size": 16681,
              "image": {
                "width": 244,
                "height": 352
              }
            },
            "fileName": "JaneDoe.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};


input.items.forEach(i => {
  const foundAsset = input.includes.Asset.find(j => j.id === i.id);
  i.fields.picture = { ...i.fields.picture,
    ...foundAsset.fields
  };
});
delete input.includes;

console.log(input);
```